# how to change soup file to 'dict' save?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've two tables with same `att:class`, and there's no other `att` for `tr` or `td`.

```
<table class='content'>
  <caption>
     <em> table1 </em>
  </caption>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
       <th> A </th>
       <th> B </th>
       <th> C </th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td> a1 <td>
       <td> b1 <td>
       <td> c1 <td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td> a2 <td>
       <td> b2 <td>
       <td> c2 <td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<table class='content'>
  <caption>
     <em> table2 </em>
  </caption>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
       <th> A </th>
       <th> B </th>
       <th> C </th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td> a3 <td>
       <td> b3 <td>
       <td> c3 <td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td> a4 <td>
       <td> b4 <td>
       <td> c4 <td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Then I want a dict like

`{table1:[ {A:[a1,a2]}, {B:[b1,b2]}, {C:[c1,c2]} ], table2:[ {A:[a3,a4]}, {B:[b3,b4]}, {C:[c3,c4]} ], }`

Can anybody help me in getting this dict, or a similar one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (also note that you have `<td>...<td>` instead of `<td>...</td>`):

```
import bs4

your_html = """..."""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(your_html)
big_dict = {}

for table in soup.find_all("table"):
    key = table.find("em").get_text().strip()
    big_dict[key] = []
    headers = []
    for th in table.find_all("th"):
        headers.append(th.get_text().strip())
        big_dict[key].append({headers[-1]: []})
    for row in table.find_all("tr"):
        for i, cell in enumerate(row.find_all("td")):
            big_dict[key][i][headers[i]].append(cell.get_text().strip())

print(big_dict)
```

Above yielded me:

`{'table1': [{'A': ['a1', 'a2']}, {'B': ['b1', 'b2']}, {'C': ['c1', 'c2']}], 'table2': [{'A': ['a3', 'a4']}, {'B': ['b3', 'b4']}, {'C': ['c3', 'c4']}]}`

Comment: great thanks. while i'm a little confused why you add "big_dict[key].append({headers[-1]: []})" rather than {headers[0]:[]}

Comment: That's because we always need to add _last_ element. Using `headers[0]` will just always use same first element.

Comment: hmm... I just feel hard to understand that why why add value to a dict from the last one.

Comment: I push values to `headers` one by one, I could do the very same thing with `big_dict`, but just do avoid another `th.get_text().strip()` call - I use already calculated `headers[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is to find the table row data, mapped to the table header linked as the table's `caption` as a key.

```
{
    table[0].caption: {
        th[n] : [
          col[n][0],
          col[n][1],
          col[n][1]]
    }
}
```

So you need to break down the task into:

- Getting the caption for the table
- Getting the table headers
- Looping over each row of the table, saving each `td`'s index as its respective column in the table.

Instead of writing the code for you, I can point you in the direction for the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree)  for doing searches in an HTML document.

Please ask more specific questions and we can give you a more direct answer though, in the future.